# “Off” VS. “Off something”

Tags: grammar, prepositions, adverbs

> - 1) Spend a hundred dollars and get 10% **off**
> - 2) Approximately, on Black Friday you get 25% **off** any item you buy.

As I know, that most prepositions have dual functions: as a preposition if it is followed by object or as an adverb if nothing comes after. Please, correct if I am wrong.

- Yesterday, I walked down the street (preposition)
- Hey buddy, do you know where I can find this store?

  Yes, it is a couple of streets down (adverb)

Does **off** in the first (1) sentence act as an adverb because nothing follows it? Or does it act as a preposition in the second sentence (2) as it is followed by an object “any item”.

Comment: Parts of speech are crude labels for syntactic function.  Syntactic function has a semantic component.  10% is deducted or stricken from your bill.  Is **off** a clausal complement?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo No, it is not.